# Custom Listview in a Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-listview

I'm trying to put a custom `ListView` in a `Dialog`. My code is as follows:

```
dialog = new Dialog(MyWallet.this);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.emergency_contacts);
dialog.setTitle("Emergency Contacts");
dialog.show();

mAdapter.addInfo("Name");
ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
if (lv != null) {
   lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

and then my custom `Adapter`:

```
    private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final int TYPE_INFO = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 1;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int noteFull = 0;

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    public void addInfo(final String info) {
        mInfo.add(info);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return TYPE_INFO;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_INFO:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emergency_contacts_list, null);
                    holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    holder.name.setText(mInfo.get(position));
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            switch(type) {
                case TYPE_INFO:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emergency_contacts_list, null);
                    holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    holder.name.setText(mInfo.get(position));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name;
    public TextView phoneNumber;
    public TextView emailAddress;
}
```

The code is crashing (with a `NullPointerException` at

holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

I'm guessing because `convertView` isn't the right view. How do I set it to the right `View`?

Edit: `Code for emergency_contacts_list`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="left">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Name">
            </TextView>
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Phone Number">
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Email Address">
            </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/call"
                android:layout_height="35px"
                android:layout_width="50px"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:layout_margin="3px"
                android:text="Call">
            </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

edit 2: Full `logcat`:

```
03-19 15:39:43.157: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellimec.MyWallet$MyCustomAdapter.getView(MyWallet.java:207)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1428)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1265)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1128)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformWidth(LinearLayout.java:594)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8524)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:915)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1991)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: does R.layout.emergency_contacts_list contain R.id.name?

Comment: Yes it does, Added edit showing emergency_contacts_list.xml

Comment: private static final int TYPE_INFO = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 1;
set TYPE_MAX_COUNT to 2 instead of 1. TYPE_MAX_COUNT Has to be set to the number of different kind of view + 1

Comment: Changed TYPE_MAX_COUNT to 2, still crashed at same line

Comment: see line no.207 in MyWallet$MyCustomAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th `NullPointerException` appears because when you get a `convertView` that isn't null(a recycled one) in the `getView()` method instead of using that you inflate a new `View` in place. The `getView()` method should be:

```
//...
 else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();     
                    holder.name.setText(mInfo.get(position));
}
//..
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your static class inside MyCustomAdapter.This is work for you.For Example

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static class ViewHolder {
public TextView name;
public TextView phoneNumber;
public TextView emailAddress;
}

}
```

Comment: you have to make constructor of MyCustomAdapter class. for more information check this link http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code of how you should be doing a layout inflater

```
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vDialogTextSize = li.inflate(R.layout.options_dialog_textsize, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.Custom_Size_Dialog));
```

all information has been derived of this site [Dialogs.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: can you explain this a little further? my dialog is not defined in my xml file, so (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.dialog) won't work..

Comment: Click the Dialogs link go to creating an alertdialog title and read from there. If you are not using custom dialog. It should give you enough for a yes and no answer. If you want more than that you got to build it using custom dialog.